# How to handle authentication and authorization process if the users data are stored in elasticsearch database?

Tags: python, django, authentication, elasticsearch

I am working on a project in which its backend side is implemented using Django framework, and its database is Elastic Search. I have seen several Django projects in which their authentication has been done using JWT(Json Web Token) and related packages.

But in my project since all the user data like first name, last name, username and password are stored in an elastic index, I do not know what is the best way to implement a secure authorization and authentication process using tokens which should have time limits.

I have searched on net, but could not find relative and helpful results. The only solution which I decided to try was to clone [Django-Rest-Simple-JWT](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/tree/c791e987332ed5e22a86428160d6372b1d85ffae) repository, and then change all of its models to elastic indices, and change all of their usages. But I think there must be better ways to handle this problem.

I will be really grateful for any advice, solution or suggestion.